# Why my frontend empty with automaketemplate after migration?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have an empty `<body>` after migration from typo3 4.5 to 6.2.10.

Hello world in body works but with the typoscript with the extension automaketemplate  there is an empty body tag. Anybody have an idea why ?

Thank you very much in advance.
Mohamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, the extension css_styled_content was not installed and selected in TS. After that it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Ganybhat, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After Migration Follow this step:

1) Upgrade all the compatible extension and disable those extension which is not compatible.

2) Check the typoscript , some of typoscript has been removed in 6.2 version. need to removed or need to replace with latest.

3) Check the install tool > upgrade wizard. is there anything that remaining to be execute ?

For error debug :
Add this into `LocalConfiguration.php` under the 'sys'

```
'debug' => '1',
'displayErrors' => '1',
'enable_DLOG' => '1',
'enable_errorDLOG' => '1',
'enable_exceptionDLOG' => '1',
```

@Mohamed Masmoudi : Just add the debug code in your `Localconfiguration.php`. that will show the error which not loading frontend.

I hope this things helps.

Comment: Thank you Jimit, i will add the debug code and will see the error.

Comment: Yes, but i have no error in php log, and the template browser show no errors. :(.
still this in use :

temp.mainTemplate = TEMPLATE
temp.mainTemplate {
  template =< plugin.tx_automaketemplate_pi1
  template.content.templateType = main
  workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY

Comment: @Mohamed Masmoudi did you solve this issue.
I have exactly the same issue, so would be nice if you could provide a hint to solution. 
Thx

Comment: @KurtLudikovsky i didn't find a solution there, i had leaved the project there.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in the admin panel :

```html
Setting language and locale  9 Locale "de_DE" not found.
Page generation  40 
page PAGE 60 Content Object "" does not exist

Content Object "" does not exist

Content Object "PHP_SCRIPT" does not exist

Include libraries
page  6 Files for inclusion: "typo3conf/ext/automaketemplate/pi1/class.tx_automaketemplate_pi1.php"

Include libraries
page  1 Files for inclusion: "typo3conf/ext/automaketemplate/pi1/class.tx_automaketemplate_pi1.php"

Page generation/XHTML clean, all  10 
Page generation/Local anchor fix, all  0 
Print Content  5
```